# AppLovin Banner Ad not Visible But It is Clickable

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, banner-ads, applovin

I am developing android game in unity with latest Applovin SDK. I am trying to Integrate Applovin Banner ad. Integration is done but still i cant see banner ad but amazing thing is, its clickable. I did saw test Ad once but after that I never saw that.

My lines of code are below

```
AppLovin.SetSdkKey ("11H8U6aELIAQxFi5y51tuGKeh872sMItNa_sga51tGRoV9uSEvK79emsnuucEBUcmTSR3TSwqxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
AppLovin.InitializeSdk ();
AppLovin.LoadRewardedInterstitial();
AppLovin.PreloadInterstitial ();
AppLovin.SetUnityAdListener (this.gameObject.name);

AppLovin.SetAdWidth (768);
AppLovin.ShowAd (AppLovin.AD_POSITION_CENTER,AppLovin.AD_POSITION_TOP);
```

Test Mode is On
Play Services integrated (Rewarded Videos and Interstitial are working fine)
Manifest is updated and No Frequency Cap is applied

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved after consulting with applovin support team. Problem was in the IDE version of Unity that I was using. Upgraded the Unity IDE and it worked.